# Populate bootstrap modal popup with data before displaying

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, modal-dialog

I'm using ASP.NET web forms with Twitter Bootstrap and HTML5.

I have a LinkButton that shows a modal pop-up with code below. The modal pop-up is just a div with a Repeater.

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-mini btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">View</a>
```

The code above correctly opens the popup, but I want to do this and fill the Repeater with data before the popup is displayed:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkView" CssClass="btn btn-mini btn-block btn-primary" 
                                            OnCommand="lnkView_Command"
                                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'>View</asp:LinkButton>
```

`lnkView_Command` would get data from db in C# code-behind.

I'm aware that the `OnCommand` also generates `<a href="" >`, but I'm not sure how to resolve using `href` to display pop-up, and also call code-behind method.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try showing an ajax loading gif, and getting rid of it when the content is loaded, or alternatively, did you try display none, then on load display block? I was going to make an answer, but I'm not 100% sure I'm sure on your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are loading the Repeater during the server-side processing of the page, when the modal opens, you are going to have to make an AJAX request to the server, get some HTML or JSON content, and update the UI all with client-side JavaScript yourself.  OR: when you go to show the popup, postback to the server, and onload show the popup.

If the former, it's not an easy task, but not impossible.  You could use a [page callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx) or a [web service](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services) to get the data.  You can really use any client-side framework like jQuery too.